# get objects from a list populated by service in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am new to angular2 and trying to do a very simple thing. I have a local json file and i am accessing it via http.get to get the data using a service. This service return a list of data and i want to access an object out of it and render on screen. I do not want to use ngFor because i have a Previous,Next feature and i want to push the object one-by-one on my user clicks into view. However my rendering fails and seems like "promoObj" in below codeis "undefined" and cannot figure out why. Below is my code -

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleService } from '../services/services.intrests';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { Promo } from '../services/model';


@Component({
    selector: 'promo-banners',
    templateUrl: 'src/components/promotion/promotion-template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./static/css/app.css']
})
export class PromotionWidget implements OnInit {

    promoList: Array<Promo>;
    promoObj: Promo;



    constructor(private titleSvc: TitleService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.retrievePromotions();
        //I want to do something like this and push the first object in view when initialized
        this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];

    }
    retrievePromotions() {
        this.titleSvc.getTitle().subscribe(data => {
            this.promoList = data;
        });

    }


}
```

In above code Promo is a class and contains attributes that are expected from json.

Below is my service file
    **service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()

export class TitleService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getTitle() {
        console.log("again");
        return this.http.get('./static/json/title.json').map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

**View.html**

```
 <div style="max-width: 30%;float: left;" class="promo-card">
        <h2>{{promoObj.title}}</h2>

    </div>
```

I know something silly i am doing but don't know what. Please help.

Comment: Doing `this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];` where you have it isn't going to work. Your network request hasn't finished yet, so your `this.promoList` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic asynchronous gotcha. Doing `this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];` where you have it isn't going to work. Your network request hasn't finished yet, so your this.promoList is empty. This would solve your issue:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.retrievePromotions().subscribe(data => {
        this.promoList = data;
        this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];
    });
}



retrievePromotions() {
    return this.titleSvc.getTitle();
}
```

The other part of your problem is that the html template is trying to access properties on `promoObj` before it is initialized. You can fix this a few ways:

Using an ngIf to gaurd the property access:

```
<div *ngIf="promoObj != null" style="max-width: 30%;float: left;" class="promo-card">
        <h2>{{promoObj.title}}</h2>

    </div>
```

or by using the "safe navigation operator":

```
<div style="max-width: 30%;float: left;" class="promo-card">
        <h2>{{promoObj?.title}}</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this earlier and below is what i get --> Cannot read property 'title' of **undefined**, looks like promoObj does not get initialized.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your subscribe block and see what `data` is. Also check your dev tools to see if the network request for your json file succeeded.

Comment: Yes everything works fine as well the console prints my object however object is printed after exception is thrown

Comment: Oh, actually, the other problem you're having is that the html template is trying to access your promoObj before it is initialized. I'll update my answer, 1 second.

Comment: does this mean that ngFor bydefault implements safe navigation behaviour. @matmo

Comment: Sort of yeah. If you have `*ngFor="let item of items"`, then it isn't going to render anything if `items` is null/undefined/empty. If thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As matmo noted earlier, your code **this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];** is trying to access and assign a value that does not exist yet at the initialization state of your component. Doing it inside the subscribe ensures that the network request is completed and you have gotten your data from your request.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleService } from '../services/services.intrests';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { Promo } from '../services/model';


@Component({
    selector: 'promo-banners',
    templateUrl: 'src/components/promotion/promotion-template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./static/css/app.css']
})
export class PromotionWidget implements OnInit {

    promoList: Array<Promo>;
    promoObj: Promo;



    constructor(private titleSvc: TitleService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.retrievePromotions();
    }

    retrievePromotions() {
        this.titleSvc.getTitle().subscribe(data => {
            this.promoList = data;
            this.promoObj = this.promoList[0];
        });

    }


}
```